# Правильно ли составленв предложения по смыслу?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, редактура

1 - Худощавое тело мальчишки, было жутко искривлено деформацией позвоночника, сильно согнувшей туловище ребенка в правую сторону и образовавшеей на спине продолговатый безобразно выпячивающий горб.

2 - При виде детей мальчик в надежде спрятаться от посторонних взглядов торопливо направился к высыхающему дереву стоявшего около дома, он попытался бежать, но деформированая левая стопа, придававшая телу покачивающуюся походку, сильной болью отдавалась в ноге, когда он ступал на неë. Из - за чего быстрые переберания ногами превращались в неуклюжую хотьбу и мальчик упал.

Comment: Только эти фразы требуют редактирования? Хорошо бы иметь общее представление.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильно ли составлены эти предложения?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471976/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)