# Правильно ли составлены эти предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, грамматика, редактура

При виде детей, мальчик торопливо направился к высохшему дереву около дома, в надежде спрятаться  за ним от посторонних острых взглядов, Он пытался быстро бежать, но деформированные стопы не позволяли этого сделать, превращая каждый шаг в испытание болью, пронизывающей всё тело и придавая ему шаткую, покачивающуюся походку. Из - за чего быстрые переберания ногами превратились в неуклюжую хотьбу и мальчик потеряв равновесие упал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Две стилистические погрешности, остальное - орфография-пунктуация.

"Из - за чего" (убрать пробелы) - это не художественный стиль, к которому стремится остальной текст, а... милицейско-протокольный.

"...болью, пронизывающей всё тело и придавая ему шаткую, покачивающуюся походку", тело с походкой - это нечто.

> Ушел походкой /
> В сияньи дня...

*При виде детей мальчик торопливо направился к высохшему дереву около дома в надежде спрятаться за ним от посторонних острых взглядов. Он пытался быстро бежать, но деформированные стопы не позволяли, превращая каждый шаг в испытание болью, пронизывающей всё тело, и придавая ему шаткую, покачивающуюся походку. Из-за этого быстрые перебирания ногами превратились в неуклюжую ходьбу, и мальчик, потеряв равновесие, упал.*

Как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Скажите пожалуйста, а можно написать так - "Худощавое тело было искривлено деформацией позвоночника"

Comment: Искривлено деформацией - тавтология, нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо! Большое